# Issues with WPF Trigger Events

Tags: c#, wpf, eventtrigger

I'm trying to create some buttons in a WPF application that have trigger events based on what is currently being done to the button. I'm having trouble adding multiple trigger events. In the code below the trigger for isPressed does not work but isMouseOver does. If I remove one of the triggers it works but they never work together.

I also need to add an image change if the button is disabled but the trigger property does not seem to contain anything for disabled. I may have to make this change in the C# code. If anyone has an idea for this it would be great!

Any help is appreciated!

```
<Button Name="testbutton"       
        Background="Transparent"
        Cursor="Hand"
        Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" ToolTip="Exits The Application">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Name="exitstatic"
                                Source="{StaticResource exit static}"
                                Stretch="Fill"
                                Visibility="Visible" />
                        <Image Name="exithover"
                                Source="{StaticResource exit hover}"
                                Stretch="Fill"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <Image Name="exitdisabled"
                                Source="{StaticResource exit disabled}"
                                Stretch="Fill"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="exitdisabled"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="exithover"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger   Property="IsMouseOver"
                                        Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="exithover"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="exitstatic"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever `IsPressed` is true, `IsMouseOver` is also true, simply because the mouse has to be there to press the thing. In effect, the `IsPressed` trigger Setters are applied, but then the `IsMouseOver` trigger Setters are applied and step on what the `IsPressed` setters did.

Reverse the order of the two triggers, so the `IsPressed` trigger will be evaluated second and step on the values set by `IsPressed` instead. This is a common gotcha with triggers.

I've never had any trouble with `<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">`, as far as your second question is concerned.

Comment: @mcavanaugh418, Agreed, the triggers are processed sequentially as listed... whatever is last wins.

Comment: Thank you Ed. It was so simple I can't believe I didn't catch that to begin with. also I must have missed the IsEnabled property. thank you for pointing it out, exactly what I needed.